# CsvHelper getting just the headers row

Tags: csvhelper

I am trying to read an uploaded CSV file and before doing anything with the data I need to check the first header name to be sure it is the correct file. I have been trying to find a way to do it but the reader skips to the second row instead. Is there a direct way of selecting one of the headers and checking its value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to get the list of column names using CsvHelper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48307466/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-the-list-of-column-names-using-csvhelper)

Answer (score 22):

You can use the CsvReader to get the header row strings as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48307798/1043475):

```
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
{
    csv.Read();
    csv.ReadHeader();
    string[] headerRow = csv.Context.HeaderRecord;
}
```

Comment: Important note on this method is that if you read the HeaderRecord, it seems to push the cursor down a row, which will result in a later call to GetRecords() having 1 fewer rows. To get around this I had to GetRecords().ToList(), then read the csv.HeaderRecord. Everything is fine if you do it like that. Also, if you don't call ToList(), the issue will persist.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the parser directly if you want to just check the first row.

```
var parser = new CsvParser( textReader );
var row = parser.Read();
if( row[0] == "MyColumn" ) { /* do something */ }
```

If you're using a `Stream`, you will need to reset it to the beginning if you're going to use it again.